# Pythonic way to read file line by line?

Tags: python

What's the Pythonic way to go about reading files line by line of the two methods below?

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

or

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print line
```

Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of the two you presented, the first is recommended practice. As pointed out in the comments, any solution (like that below) which doesn't use a context manager means that the file is left open, which is a bad idea.

**Original answer which leaves dangling file handles so shouldn't be followed**
However, if you don't need `f` for any purpose other than reading the lines, you can just do:

```
for line in open('file', 'r'):
    print line
```

Comment: Won't this leave an open file handle?

Comment: There is really no need to use a context manager for files open for reading in scripts that aren't long-running. For writes, where you want to make sure the data made it out of the buffers when the write is done, you should always use one.

Comment: @agf -- While you're right, isn't it always a good idea to use good practices?  building good habits in your short scripts can only make your more indepth scripts more robust.

Comment: @mgilson Don't code defensively. Don't write more code than you need. Those are also good habits that will serve you well in larger programs.

Comment: @agf -- Maybe.  I hardly consider 1 extra line of extremely idiomatic code to be "coding defensively" or excessive in any way.

Comment: @agf Could you explain the relation between a long/short run and the use of a context manager ? I don't see the point.

Comment: @DaveP Opening the file as you do, without a handler that allows to shut it, is a bad thing. I once had the proof of that : having opened a file like in your code,  a process was still alive in background that was not seen, even in the Task Manager. It was perturbating the activity of my computer, because it was an old computer with ancient operating system, little RAM, etc. Since then, I never open file that I can't explicitly shut, and I preferably use the `with` statement.

Comment: @eyquem The file will be closed when the program ends, at worst. If the program will only be running briefly, there is probably no need to close a file sooner, as you're unlikely to run into resource limits in that time, which is the most common problem caused by not closing files.

Comment: Another point: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/618ea5612e83/Lib/_pyio.py#l352 when the file object is deleted, which because of reference counting in CPython is immediately when the `for` loop in the example ends, the file will be closed anyway. The context manager doesn't make any difference at all in that case.

Comment: @mgilson My point was that from a "good practices" standpoint you can make the argument either way, since it doesn't actually matter as far as the success of the program is concerned.

Comment: @agf -- I don't agree, but I'll let you have the last word.  Agree to disagree?

Answer (score 12):

File handles are their own iterators (specifically, they implement the iterator protocol) so

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    # code
```

Is the preferred usage.  `f.readlines()` returns a list of lines, which means absorbing the entire file into memory -> generally ill advised, especially for large files.

It should be pointed out that I agree with the sentiment that context managers are worthwhile, and have included one in my code example.

Answer (score 1):

theres' no need for .readlines() method call.

**PLUS:** About *with* statement

The execution behavior of with statement is as commented below,

```
with open("xxx.txt",'r') as f:    
                                  // now, f is an opened file in context
    for line in f:
        // code with line

pass                              // when control exits *with*, f is closed
print f                           // if you print, you'll get <closed file 'xxx.txt'>
```